# npm install command doing nothing

Tags: git, npm, yeoman, gruntjs

I have a package.json with the following contents:

```
{
  "name": "useless-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.6.6",
    "grunt-contrib-jst": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.4.3",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "0.1.3",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "0.1.4",
    "grunt-contrib-livereload": "0.1.2",
    "grunt-mocha": "~0.3.1",
    "grunt-bower-requirejs": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-usemin": "~0.1.10",
    "grunt-requirejs": "~0.3.5",
    "grunt-regarde": "~0.1.1",
    "grunt-open": "~0.2.0",
    "matchdep": "~0.1.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.0"
  }
}
```

Which is what Yeoman built for me as standard. When I call `npm install` or `npm install -g` I get no action, just this:

```
Alex@iMac-2 ~/Sites/Backbone/Yeoman$ sudo npm install -g
useless-app@1.0.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/useless-app
```

At this point I was somewhat expecting a list of applications being downloaded and installed. Either way, testing this by running grunt (one of the items from the list), results in the following:

```
Alex@iMac-2 ~/Sites/Backbone/Yeoman$ grunt
-bash: grunt: command not found
```

Any ideas why these things aren't installing?

I have tried using `sudo` for these commands and the result is always the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you installed grunt-cli? Remember that in the newest versions of Grunt you need to have grunt-cli in order to execute `grunt` commands.

Try `sudo npm install -g grunt-cli`

Best regards,
Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encounters a problem like this try running `rm -rf node_modules` on your terminal and run `npm install` again.