# Unexpected npm module install script behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm

I'm getting some rather unexpected behaviour when installing (a private) dependency.

For questions sake lets assume I have two packages:

```
{
  "name": "Package_A",
   ....
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "Package_B": ""      
  }
}
```

And

```
{
  "name": "Package_B",
  "scripts": {
    "install": "grunt"
  },
   ....
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0"      
  }
}
```

Now when I run npm install on (a fresh) Package_A, Package_B installs with `grunt-contrib-clean` as a dependency and runs grunt (which uses clean). It all works fine.

Now as soon as I add `grunt-contrib-clean` to Package_A dependencies and run install (fresh copy again) fails.
the npm install script runs grunt, and grunt cannot find `grunt-contrib-clean`:

> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-clean" not found. Is it installed?

I'm not really sure where to go from here. I was wondering if I'm having a similar issue to [NPM doesn't install module dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401606/npm-doesnt-install-module-dependencies). But I don't know enough about npm or grunt to tell.

Comment: I just tried changing the Package_B install script to `npm install && grunt package`, it installed the dependencies but then infinitely loops over the command without doing anything :/

Comment: ^^ thats because npm install is calling the install script :/

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
Changing the script from install to prepublish works

```
 "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "grunt package"
  },
```

Must be something to do with the order of operations when installing. Quirky.

---

## Damn it

(Update)

[Npm doesn't run prepublish](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3055) when installing from a git repo ([when it probably should](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3055#issuecomment-35562116)).

Comment: Does the same thing as install :(