# gulp-sass isuee while running npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have all updated version of node,npm,sass but when i add gulp-sass in gulpfile and run `npm start` its showing following error:

> ```
> $ npm start
>
> > Dashboard@1.0.0 start D:\Projects\Dashboard
> > gulp
>
> module.js:327
>     throw err;
>     ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'ansi-regex'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
>     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\Dashboard\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\gulp-util\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\strip-ansi\index.js:2:17)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
>     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
> ```

Comment: try to remove folder node_modules and execute `npm install`. sometimes npm don't resolve fine module dependencies. i think you have an issue similar [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401606/npm-doesnt-install-module-dependencies)

Comment: What do you mean by "add gulp-sass in gulpfile," and what is your `start` task?

Comment: i want to complie sass file to css. for that i follow the follwing steps :           1) npm install gulp-sass -save  
2). add cssBuild = require('gulp-css')
3) create task  
gulp.task('html', function () {
   ......
});