# npm install dependencies of local modules

Tags: npm

I'm having trouble using npm with a local module. My project's structure looks like:

```
package.json
local_module/
    - package.json
    - gulpfile.json
gulpfile.js
```

The main project's `package.json` is essentially:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "local_module": "file:local_module"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "..."
    }
}
```

The local module's `package.json` is essentially:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "prepublish": "gulp release"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "..."
    }
}
```

My intention is keep my project modular by keeping `local_module` as its own package that is used as a dependency for the main project. I want to run `npm install` in the main project and use `local_module` from `node_modules`. However, `local_module` needs `gulp` installed to run the prepublish step, and when running `npm install` from the main project, it does not install the dependencies for `local_module`, and so gulp isn't installed, so it can't do the prepublish step.

Several questions like this have been asked, like [NPM doesn't install module dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401606/npm-doesnt-install-module-dependencies), but many are old and there are so many versions of npm that I can't get a clear solution.

How can I get npm to install `local_module`'s dependencies before the prepublish step? I tried adding a preinstall step for the main project, e.g.

```
"preinstall": "cd local_module && npm install"
```

But it seems npm tries to run the prepublish step of `local_module` before running the preinstall for the main project. I want a solution that will do this in one `npm install` step rather than having a separate step before this to do `npm install` in the local module.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that will work for me in the immediate future. I changed `local_module`'s `package.json` to:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "prepublish": "npm install --ignore-scripts && gulp release"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "..."
    }
}
```

When `npm install` is run from the main project, the prepublish step is run first in `local_module`, so I force prepublish to also do an install so that gulp is available to do the actual prepublish step. This is hardly ideal however.