# NPM local module - dependencies are not installed when using npm install from 'host package.json'

Tags: node.js, npm

Many of the same questions have been asked before [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874567/npm-install-dependencies-of-local-modules), but none give a solid answer or are very outdated, so just asking again.

I have a `package.json` with a local npm module:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "local_module": "file:..pathtomodule"
  }
}
```

when i run `npm i` for the host package, the local module is installed, but modules from the local_module are not installed. So I have to run a separate `npm i` for the local_module.

What am i doing wrong?? isn't it ***just a module***??

p.s. why am i getting minus for the question? please explain so I can improve

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What I use to do in that case is to "force" dependencies to be "npm installed" using preinstall script in the root module:

```
   {
      "dependencies": {
        "local_module": "file:..pathtomodule"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "preinstall": "npm install ..pathtomodule"
      }
    }
```