# NPM peer dependencies issue while building vis-timeline locally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install, vis.js

I am using vis-timelime in one of my projects. I have done some changes in vis-timeline, then locally build it and using it as dependency in my project. While doing so, vis-timeline is getting installed properly but i believe the peer dependencies of vis-timeline are not coming. Do note that I'm using npm version - 7.6.3.

```
cd vis-timeline;
//added some console logs in few files
npm install;
npm run build;
```

Then in my project-

```
cd my-app
npm install local-path-to-my-vis-timeline
```

Running above commands install the vis-timeline in node_modules of my-app. However, other peer dependencies of vis-timeline like vis-data, etc. do not come automatically. Since I am using npm version 7.6.3, wasn't it supposed to happen automatically?? If not, any graceful solution to this?
Or let me know of any other better way to locally do changes in vis-timeline library and use it in my local project for debugging.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like an issue with npm. [This post has a list of solutions that might work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401606/npm-doesnt-install-module-dependencies)

Otherwise, maybe try using yarn instead of npm?